# Three.js panoroma viewer - images loading in mobile very slow

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three js panroma viewer based on this "//codepen.io/w3core/pen/vEVWML".
My images around 2 TO 1.6 mb and its full image not cropped collections, In desktop its loading fine.

But in mobile devices , It loads very very long time.

any way to speed up this.